# Though my code passes some of the testcases I am unable to find error why it is not passing one testcase

Tags: c++, string, stl

Given two strings s1 and s2, return true if s2 contains a permutation of s1, or false otherwise.

In other words, return true if one of s1's permutations is the substring of s2.
This is a leetcode question

here is my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool checkInclusion(string s1, string s2) {
        
        do
        {   
            if(s2.find(s1)<s2.length())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }while(next_permutation(s1.begin(),s1.end()));
        
        return false;
    }
};
```

but its not working for the testcase
"abcdxabcde"
"abcdeabcdx"

I would appreciate for finding error in my logic.

Comment: The value you are searching for is not a `next_permutation` of `s1`. It is a `prev_permutation` of `s1`. If you sort `s1` before you start then `next_permutation` will produce the `s2` pattern.

Comment: You don't need to generate every permutation. Two strings are permutations of each other if they have the same characters; check that by sorting each string and testing the resulting strings for equality.

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool checkInclusion(string s1, string s2) {
        
        do
        {   
            if(s2.find(s1) != string::npos)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }while(next_permutation(s1.begin(),s1.end()));
        
        return false;
    }
};
```

If you look at the reference for `find`, you will see that not finding the string results in `std::string::npos`.

Comment: still not passing testcase